# Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I just install Laravel passport as follow:

Admin Model:

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'admins';
}
```

I just have one guard in auth.php which is API and it's by default.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'admins',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

LoginController:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Resources\LoginRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->jsonResponse(null, trans('auth.failed'), 401);
        }

        $admin = Auth::user();

        $token =  $admin->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;

        return (new AdminResourse($admin))->additional([
            'meta' => ['token' => $token]
        ]);
    }
}
```

I got this error in postman:

```
Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.
```

I clear the cache too, and still same error

Comment: can you show full logincontroller code.Also try Auth::guard('api')->attempt(

Comment: have you tried Auth::guard('api')->attempt(

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes, it shows the same error!

Comment: can you show route for that

Comment: in api.php | Route::post('login',  LoginController::class);

Comment: updated my answer .i got same error when i change to  'guard' => 'api',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `attempt` is only available for routes with web middleware.
However you can do:

```
        if (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) {
            return $this->jsonResponse(null, trans('auth.failed'), 401);
        }
```

Comment: Good answer....even i didnt tried changing default guard till now

Comment: hehe, happy to help! @JohnLobo

Answer (score 0):

The issue with default guard. So it should be `web`

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

If you keep `defaults guard` to `api` then we should manually pass guard

```
if (!Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
}
```

Comment: I did import correctly like you mention, this is not the porblem

Comment: I don't have any web route! it just API project why I need web!?